# How to permanently turn off reminders?

Tags: calendar, huawei

I have a Huawei P8 Lite phone. The phone isn't rooted. I primarily use Google Calendar, but of course another one, named Calendar (I guess it's Huawei's own) is also installed and has also access to my Google Calendars. I would like to use reminders quite often, but both of the calendars throw them at me when they are due and it's a little bit annoying. I tried to turn it off in the Huawei Calendar, but every now and then when I restart the phone the settings are turned back on to show me the notifications.

Is there a reason Calendar doesn't remember its own settings between resets and is there a way to fix that and make the notifications go away permanently?

Comment: Would turning off reminders in Google Calendar solve your issue? You can find that in the Calendar app when pressing the "overflow menu button", select "Settings", then "General", and un-tick "Notifications".

Comment: It probably would. I would prefer to keep using Google Calendar and have its reminders turned on.

Comment: OK, understood. Just mentioning: I was in a similar situation, with each alarm causing 3 notifications on my Pebble (I'm using Business Calendar). Turned off notifications in Google calendar, issue solved: just 1 notification shown. Not sure why it tripled (doubled I'd understand). So keep this as a fallback in case there's no other solution :)